# cout not printing anything to console

Tags: c++, gdb, cout

I am trying to use `cout` to print out c strings from a dynamically allocated 2D char array called `charArray`. The snippet where I am printing is here:

```
for(int k=0; k<intSize; k++)
{
    std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<charArray[intSize-1-k]<<std::endl;
}


for(int i = 0; i<intSize; i++)
{
    delete [] charArray[i];
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
delete [] charArray;
```

`intSize` is how many C strings are in `charArray`. However, when I run the program, `"hello"` is printed once, and nothing else prints, not the `charArray` nor the i in the second for loop. I already confirmed earlier in my code that `charArray` is properly filled by successfully using `cout`. I ran gdb to try and find the issue, and in gdb the for loops are fully iterating through, so for some reason after the first `cout`, the couts stop working. I also tried to flush after every `cout`, but still the same thing.

Comment: The problem is in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: _However, when I run the program, "hello" is printed once_: Either `intSize` is 1 or your program dies while accessing `charArray[intSize-1-k]`. Please, reproduce and post your issue in/with a [mcve].

Comment: Note that `std::endl` flushes the output, so adding an explicit flush, as you've seen, won't change the result. But flushing isn't the issue here; a plain `'\n'` would work as well, without the extra overhead of flushing more often than needed.

Comment: _in gdb the for loops are fully iterating through_ ...or you print something which brings `std::cout` in an error state. (You could check this e.g. `if (!std::cout.good()) std::cerr << "Oops!\n";`.)

Comment: Yet another thought (a follow-up to my previous comment): If you print to a terminal you might print non-printable characters which form special terminal commands. This may change the terminal state e.g. to non-printing. (A possible indicator would be if `std::cout` is always good or `std::cerr` doesn't work as well.)

Comment: I did what Scheff suggested, and it turns out I am doing something that brings cout into an error state. After the first "hello" is printed, I am getting a bunch of "Oops". Any suggestions on how to fix? I will keep searching online tomorrow morning

Comment: @bob -- re: "Any suggestions on how to fix?" -- the problem is still in the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const char*nul = nullptr;
    std::cout << "before "<< nul << "after\n";
 }
```

The output will be:

```
 before
```

This is what is happening to you - you are trying to print a nullptr string. 
One of `charArray[intSize-1-k]` is null. Possibly reading it out of bounds. Writing a null string sets badbit to `std::cout`.

To avoid this there are two things you can do:

1. Validate that a `char*` is not null, before printing it.
2. `std::cout.exceptions(std::ostream::failbit);` will make `operator<<` throw an exception at the offending line of code. A debugger  can catch the exception, and let you find your bug easily (gdb has `catch throw`). If you have an exception handler, don't forget to have it call `std::cout.clear();`.

Comment: Turns out the last element of the array was not being properly filled and thus cout was printing a nullptr after the "hello". Thanks for the help